# JToggleButton with underlined Text

Tags: swing, jbutton

Well, the title says it.

In Netbeans I can change the Font of a JToggleButton, but there are only options for bold and italic, but not for underlined text. I guess it's not strictly a font property, but I can't find out how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use HTML to render many components in Swing (see [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)), so you could create a String with the underlined text and call `JToggleButton.setText(String)` or `JToggleButton(String)`. For example

```
new JToggleButton("<html><u>" + textToUnderline + "</u></html>");
```

(That closing `</html>` tag is optional by the way, though I always include it).

Comment: Also beware that using HTML will prevent baselines alignment (as used by several LayoutManagers) from working properly. I always strongly advise against using HTML in Swing components. In the current context, I guess one could subclass JToggleButton and override paintComponent() or possibly work at LAF level (but this is more difficult).